# WPF Intercept GoBack() event

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, navigation

I'm creating a WPF Application in .NET Core 3.1. I structured the project with a single main window and use the navigation between different pages.
In the main page I've got a  tag and in C# file I use this code:

```
public partial class Main : Window
{
    private void ListProducts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new ListProducts(Frame));
    }
}
```

From this page I go to another page doing some stuff:

```
public partial class ListProducts : Page
{
    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new AddProduct(Frame));
    }
}
```

and then I go back with this code:

```
public partial class AddProduct : Page
{
    private void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        frame.NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
}
```

injecting the frame from page to page. When I use the GoBack(), I'd like to catch and to trigger some events in ListProducts page. How to intercept the GoBack() event in parent window?

Comment: Move Close button to parent window, you may even display it above the frame, close current page on click. Btw, learn MVVM and Bindings as things that will open the power of WPF for you. NavigationWindow+Frame+Page isn't a popular practice in WPF because it was designed by Microsoft in a wrong way containing undesirable restrictions.

Comment: @MicheleBoscagin: `ListProducts` cannot possibly intercept something that happens in `AddProduct`. Do you mean that you want to perform some actions in `ListProducts` when it gets navigated back to, or do you want to stop the navigation from happening based on some logic?

Comment: @mm8 No, simply perfome some actions in ListProduct when it get navigated back from AddProduct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `Loaded` event for `ListProducts` and perform any logic you want in the event handler:

```
public partial class ListProducts : Page
{
    private readonly Frame _frame;

    public ListProducts(Frame frame)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        _frame = frame;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_frame.CanGoForward)
        {
            //handle navigate back logic here...
        }
    }
}
```